# This question about fluoride should not be marked duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28147/is-this-list-of-facts-about-fluoride-correct

This question has been marked duplicate of

[Is fluoride toothpaste dangerous?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/792/is-fluoride-toothpaste-dangerous)

The problem with this, is that the question is posted lists several *very specific* claims about fluoride.

While several of the claims have been asked individually here

eg.

[Is fluoride in water an industry waste product?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/is-fluoride-in-water-an-industry-waste-product?rq=1)

[Did the Nazis maliciously fluoridate drinking water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/did-the-nazis-maliciously-fluoridate-drinking-water?rq=1)

The question should remain open so that these *specific claims* can be addressed, rather than an open ended 'Is fluoride dangerous?'.

Comment: Oddthinking's answer suggests it could be reopened if you could identify one claim that interests you.

Answer (score 2):

The question has two different problems.

The first is that it is too broad - if someone has a strong evidence-based answer to *one* of the claims, they can't post it, because it doesn't answer all of the questions. The current list of questions should be closed as Too Broad, as it is unfair to expect an answerer to address all of the claims. It should be broken up into several individual questions to address each claim.

The second is that we already have answers to some of the claims. They are duplicates. The question should be closed as a Duplicate.

I don't feel strongly about which close reason should be used. If you would prefer Too Broad, I would change it. The benefit of Duplicate is that it tells the reader we already have answers to (some of) these questions so there's no need to wait, you can look around for an answer.